# Can't maintain the list integrity of my linked list after performing a reverse linked list function

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to keep my original linked list ("start" node variable located in my header file under my class object) unchanged when going through this function which outputs the linked list I already stored in "start" in reverse order. The function works correctly, but after one loop in the while loop, my original linked list becomes a series of endless pointers pointing to the numbers 11 and 21 over and over again (for example, the original list contains numbers such as 11, 21, 35, 4, ...etc, but after one loop in the while loop, it goes to 11, 21, 11, 21...etc). When I debug the program, I can identify that the point where this happens is when I am moving the debug cursor from:

```
next->link = tempStart;
```

to

```
tempStart = next;
```

I just can't seem to identify a workaround or an explanation for this happening. If anybody happens to know how to solve this issue, I would very greatly like to hear what you have to say. Thank you.

```
void IntegerListClass::OutputReverseList(ofstream& fout)
{
int index;

nodePtr tempStart = start;
nodePtr next;
nodePtr current =  NULL;

if (start == NULL)
{
    return;
}

current = start;

current = current->link;

while (current != NULL) 
{
    next = current;

    current = current->link;

    next->link = tempStart;

    tempStart = next;
}

current = tempStart;

for (index = 0; index <= numberInList - 1; index++)
{
    if (index % 5 == 0)
    {
        fout << endl;
    }

    fout << setw(10) << current->data.number;

    current = current->link;
}
```

header File portion:

```
#ifndef IntegerListClass_h
#define IntegerListClass_h

#include "Standards.h"

//Create a type for the data members
struct nodeType
{
    int number;
};

//Create a  node with a pointer to set for the link node
struct node
{
    nodeType data;
    node* link;
};

//Create a type definition, which is a pointer to the node
typedef node* nodePtr;

class IntegerListClass
{
private:
    nodePtr start;
```

Comment: Please give you code for `nodePtr`

Comment: If you do not update 'start', after reversing the list, how do you expect to save the new start of the reversed link list, for the second time you call this? Not only that, but after reversing the list, you need to set start->link=nullptr, that is the original start's, since it's now the last element in the reversed list.

Comment: typedef node* nodePtr;

    class IntegerListClass
    {
    private:
      nodePtr start;

Comment: Just edit your initial post. Look for small *edit* link under you post.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I don't intend to call the function a second time. And the new start for the reversed linked list is saved in 'current = tempStart;'

Comment: @IvanGritsenko OK. I put it up. Thank you for staying with me this long.